# How to remove &nbsp; in wordpress editor

Tags: php, html, wordpress, editor

Why i got   in wordpress editor, when i am copy and paste text from MS Word. 
how to fix it?
i try to use str_replace it not working?

it makes the look so ugly when displayed on mobile.
this is the Screenshot.

[image]

Comment: copy from ms word to your notepad and then copy from notepad and paste it to wordpress it will work

Comment: yah when user like as,,, but, the user dont understand code. they are confused, can make automatic? Thanks

Comment: no because  both use different characterset so from my opininon directly its not possible , it happens because word file characterset is not compatible by wordpress or its format so

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the below solutions:

```
$content = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', get_the_content() );

echo $content;
```

Or

```
$content = str_replace('&nbsp;'," ",get_the_content());

$content = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $content );

echo $content;
```

Create a child theme if you haven't done it yet. Then copy paste the source files of the pages that this happens (like single.php) and replace the `get_the_content()` with one of the above. Depending the actual issue.

[Original source](http://wpquestions.com/question/showChrono/id/7931)

Edit: I agree with the others that it would be better to explain to your clients why it is better if they don't use Word for this or if they do, they copy paste it first on notepad to remove styling.

Comment: I tried both still not work, and, why in the name of product also exists &nbsp;

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code on the file you edit?

Answer (score -1):

Remove 
 tag from here [image]
do backspace before df;lkgmjkdflgdf` and ;ldfgkhd;f 
I hope this will hepls you.